# Comparing two TSV files, and then ajoining them in Python

Tags: python, comparison, csv

I've done most of the work, but this is a niggling problem that I can't for the life of me fix.

So, I have two TSV files that look a little something like this.

**File One**

```
"Cars"    2
"Cars"    1
"Bikes"    21
```

**File Two**

```
"Bikes"   21    "Triumph"
"Cars"    2     "vauxhall.jpg"
```

I would like to correlate the second file to the first one, so I end up with something like...

```
"Cars"    2     "vauxhall.jpg"
"Bikes"   21    "Triumph"
```

How would I go about doing this in Python? I have tried this...

```
import csv

with open("../csvfiles/created/redandyellow.csv","rb") as rayf:
    rayfs = csv.reader(rayf, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n')

    with open("../csvfiles/photos.csv","rb") as phf:
            phfs = csv.reader(phf, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\n')

            for phrow in phfs:
                    for rayrow in rayfs:
                            if phrow[1] == rayrow[1]:                                                  
                                    print phrow[1] + ", " + phrow[1]
```

To no avail.

Comment: did it print anything and i think the if condition should be like `if phrow[1] == rayrow[1] and phrow[0] == rayrow[0] :`

Comment: It did not I'm afraid

Comment: Instead of the `if-statement` try `print(phrow, rayrow)` (or use a debugger) to inspect the values and find out what is going on. You may find there are spaces which make `phrow[1]` different than `rayrow[1]`...

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond, I know that. The files do not relate in terms of order.

Comment: is it print the same word like `Cars` `Bikes` and not other thing even case sensitivity matters

Comment: @KeironO: Find a line in the output for which you *expect* `phrow[1]` *should* equal `rayrow[1]`. Investigate why Python thinks the two strings are not equal.